# Possible to put a text input within a radio input? Or more semantically appropriate solution?

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I have a radio button that needs to accept an input (when denoting 'Other'):
[image: Other input]

What is the best way to do this, both in regards to semantics and ease? I don't really want to take the functionality of all the other radios if I don't have to.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking.

Comment: Apologies - the different amounts ($60, $120, $360, $1020 and Other) are a single set of customized radio buttons. Which is all fine and dandy unless the user selects "Other," where I then need to accept a numerical input. But I'm not sure how to capture an input within a radio button. Is that more clear?

Comment: Add separate <input type="text">, visible (JS) only when "Other" radio button is selected. Style accordingly.

Comment: If you're using JavaScript your donation amounts don't have to actually be an `<input>` at all. They could simply be a styled `div` and when clicked on you update the value of a hidden input. The Other option could be a text input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threw this together pretty quick. Should get you most of the way there: http://codepen.io/chrisdpratt/pen/doBkb

**HTML**

```
<ol class="radios">
  <li class="selected">
    <input id="Amount60" type="radio" name="amount" checked="checked" value="60">
    <label for="Amount60">$60</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="Amount120" type="radio" name="amount" value="120">
    <label for="Amount120">$120</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="Amount360" type="radio" name="amount" value="360">
    <label for="Amount360">$360</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="Amount1020" type="radio" name="amount" value="1020">
    <label for="Amount1020">$1020</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="AmountOther" type="radio" name="amount" value="">
    <label for="AmountOther">Other</label>
    $<input type="text" name="other" placeholder="Enter amount here">
  </li>
</ol>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  font-size:100%;
  line-height:1.4;
  font-family:heveltica,arial,sans-serif;
}

.radios, .radios li {
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.radios li {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:10px;
  border:1px solid #222;
  background:#fff;
  color:#222;
}
.radios label
{
  display:inline-block;
  min-width:3em;
  padding:15px;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.radios li:first-child {
  margin-left:0;
}
.radios .selected {
  background:#222;
  color:#fff;
}
.radios [type=radio] {
  position:absolute;
  left:-9999px;
  width:0;
  height:0;
}
.radios [type=text] {
  width:8.5em;
  padding:2px;
  margin-right:15px;
  border:0;
  background:transparent;
  color:#222;
  border-bottom:1px solid #222;
}
.radios .selected [type=text] {
  color:#fff;
  border-color:#fff;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.radios [type=radio]').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
      var $radios = $(this).closest('.radios');
      var $li = $(this).closest('li');
      $radios.find('li').removeClass('selected');
      $li.addClass('selected');

      $li.find('[type=text]').focus();
    }
  })
});
```

Just to clarify. Based on this setup, if you see that the value for `amount` is blank (which it will be when the "Other" radio is selected), then you look for the amount in the `other` field, your text box.

Comment: Chris Pratt, you are a gentleman and a scholar. Thank you so much!